# the new kernel(3.9.6) configs for solving acpi=off in lenovo laptops

Tags: linux-kernel, 64-bit, linux-mint, acpi

i have a Lenovo Z580 IDeaPAd Laptop and want to boot my linux with acpi.but with its kernel i must to set acpi off in the kernel i read more about this in net and found that must use new kernels above 3.8.
i donwload every kernels in the kernel.org.
i want to set the configs but i dont know any thing and use the previous kernel configs to compile.
i want to know what configs should i do and set for solving the acpi problem.
i ahve linuxmint 14 and linuxmint 15 and have kernels: 3.9.3 3.9.4 and 3.9.6.

Answer (score 1):

If you have working linux-kernel, before compile of kernel use command

> make oldconfig

This make config with working old params.

Try install previus version of Mint, which use 3.8.* kernel. Compile kernel with old-config and upgrade system.

Comment: thank you sir.but i want to use from the new kernels.can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Download the kernel tarball from [kernel.org](http://www.kernel.org), then execute the following:

```
$ tar xvzf kernel-xxx.tar.gz
$ cp /book/config-`uname -r` .config
$ make oldconfig # use default value for all prompt
$ make
$ make modules_install
$ make install
```